Is there any way to get notify whenever new process , daemon and application is launched ? MACOS
I tried with NSWorkspace but i able to identify when application is lauched not process not any daemon.
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: NSWorkspace.didLaunchApplicationNotification, object: nil, queue: nil)

let source = DispatchSource.makeProcessSource(identifier: pid, eventMask: [.fork], queue: queue)
 source.setEventHandler(handler: completion)
 source.resume()

dispatchsource always tell if new process is launched but no information about child process

Use KQueue or FSEvents to Monitor /proc Directory
import Foundation

// Setup KQueue to monitor the `/proc` directory for new process creation
let procPath = "/proc"
let kqueue = kqueue()
var event = kevent(ident: UInt(procPath.hashValue), filter: EVFILT_VNODE, flags: EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE, fflags: NOTE_WRITE, data: 0, udata: nil)

let fd = open(procPath, O_RDONLY)
kevent(kqueue, &event, 1, nil, 0, nil)

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    var eventList = [kevent()]
    
    while true {
        let eventCount = kevent(kqueue, nil, 0, &eventList, 1, nil)
        if eventCount > 0 {
            print("New process or daemon launched!")
        }
    }
}

also for Audit System
modify /etc/security/audit_control to log exec events. Add the following line to the flags in audit_control:
flags:lo,aa,ex

restart the audit daemon:
sudo audit -s

Tail the audit logs in your Swift program to track new processes and daemons.
import Foundation

let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/tail"
task.arguments = ["-f", "/var/audit/current"]

let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
fileHandle.readabilityHandler = { handle in
    let data = handle.availableData
    if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("New process or daemon detected: \(output)")
    }
}

You can continue using DispatchSource, but to also capture child processes, you’ll need to monitor process forks and track their parent-child relationships using pid information.
let pid: pid_t = 1 // Replace with process ID to track (e.g., `launchd`)
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()

let source = DispatchSource.makeProcessSource(identifier: pid, eventMask: [.fork, .exec], queue: queue)

source.setEventHandler {
    print("Process forked or executed")
}

source.setCancelHandler {
    print("Source cancelled")
}

source.resume()


I don't want to use an infinite loop to get new process information. Process tail does not give the child process information. The same goes for DispatchSource. DispatchSource notifies me whenever a new process is forked or exec, but information about the child process is not provided anywhere.
